# Panel not switch

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to switch a new panel after I clicked a button. I created a panel with two tabs (notebook) and each tab has buttons. These buttons will switch into a new panel when it is clicked. However, I faced some errors. This is my code:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ This will be the first notebook tab """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #txtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        #txtTwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")

        button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button One", (0, 20), size = (200, 30))
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSwitchPanels1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #sizer.Add(txtOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        #sizer.Add(txtTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onSwitchPanels1(self, event):
        if self.tab_one.IsShown():
            self.SetTitle("Test")
            self.tab_one.Hide()
            self.panel_one.Show()
        else:
            self.SetTitle("Test")
            self.tab_one.Show()
            self.panel_one.Hide()
        self.Layout()

 ########################################################################
class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    """ This is for panel switch """
    def ___init___(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.___init___(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        button8 = wx.Button(self, label="T2D", pos=(0, 0))

########################################################################
class NotebookDemo(wx.Notebook):
    """ Notebook class """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=
                             wx.BK_DEFAULT
                             #wx.BK_TOP 
                             #wx.BK_BOTTOM
                             #wx.BK_LEFT
                             #wx.BK_RIGHT
                             )

        # Create the first tab and add it to the notebook
        tabOne = TabPanel(self)
        self.AddPage(tabOne, "TabOne")

        # Create and add the second tab
        tabTwo = TabPanel(self)
        self.AddPage(tabTwo, "TabTwo")

########################################################################
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ Frame that holds all other widgets """
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Notebook Tutorial",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = NotebookDemo(panel)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

        self.tab_one = TabPanel(self)
        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.panel_one.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tab_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I've tried a few solutions but it seem doesn't work. This is the error I got:

```
AttributeError: 'TabPanel' object has no attribute 'tab_one'
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Where is your question?

Answer (score 0):

there some points to remeber

1. to move from one page to other you need to use `notebook.SetSelection(<index>)`
2. if you want to get methods of other class in your notebook class you need to have `self.tabOne, self.tabTwo`

Try This:

```
import wx


class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    """ This will be the first notebook tab """
    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.parent=parent
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #txtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        #txtTwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")

        button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button One", (0, 20), size = (200, 30))
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSwitchPanels1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #sizer.Add(txtOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        #sizer.Add(txtTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onSwitchPanels1(self, event):
        #if self.tab_one.IsShown():
            #self.SetTitle("Test")
        self.parent.SetSelection(1)
        #self.TabPanel.Hide()
        #self.NotebookDemo.tabTwo.Show()
        #else:
            # self.SetTitle("Test")
            # self.tab_one.Show()
            # self.panel_one.Hide()
        self.Layout()
```

---

```
class TabPanel2(wx.Panel):
    """ This will be the first notebook tab """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.parent=parent

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #txtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        #txtTwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")

        button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button Two", (0, 20), size = (200, 30))
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSwitchPanels2)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #sizer.Add(txtOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        #sizer.Add(txtTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onSwitchPanels2(self, event):
        pass
        #if self.tab_one.IsShown():
            #self.SetTitle("Test")
        #self.TabPanel.Hide()
        #self.NotebookDemo.tabTwo.Show()
        #else:
            # self.SetTitle("Test")
            # self.tab_one.Show()
            # self.panel_one.Hide()
        self.Layout()
```

---

```
class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    """ This is for panel switch """
    def ___init___(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.___init___(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        button8 = wx.Button(self, label="T2D", pos=(0, 0))
```

---

```
class NotebookDemo(wx.Notebook):
    """ Notebook class """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=
                             wx.BK_DEFAULT
                             #wx.BK_TOP
                             #wx.BK_BOTTOM
                             #wx.BK_LEFT
                             #wx.BK_RIGHT
                             )

        # Create the first tab and add it to the notebook
        self.tabOne = TabPanel(self)
        self.AddPage(self.tabOne, "TabOne")

        # Create and add the second tab
        self.tabTwo = TabPanel2(self)
        self.AddPage(self.tabTwo, "TabTwo")


class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ Frame that holds all other widgets """
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "Notebook Tutorial",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = NotebookDemo(panel)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

        self.tab_one = TabPanel(self)
        self.panel_one = PanelOne(self)
        self.panel_one.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tab_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = DemoFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        #self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True


app = MyApp(0)
#Colours(None, -1, 'colours.py')
app.MainLoop()
```